# NosuchMethodException when I try to create an object using reflexion

Tags: java, constructor

I have a class called `BankAccount` with 2 constructors, one with no argument and the second take an int as a parameter:

```
public final class BankAccount {

    private int balance;
    public String name;

    public BankAccount() {

    }

    public BankAccount(int startBalance) {
        balance = startBalance;
    }
}
```

so when I try to create an object using the constructor with the integer param 
like this :

```
    try {
        BankAccount account = BankAccount.class.getConstructor(Integer.class).newInstance(100);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the exception of `NosuchMethodException`.

Comment: Why don't you use `new BankAccount(100);` ?

Comment: Autoboxing may not work here. You don't have a constructor with an Integer. Either convert the constructor to an Integer or call the getConstructor with an int.

Comment: Your constructor takes `int` not `Integer`, so instead of `Integer.class` use `int.class` or `Integer.TYPE`.